# jquery selector question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i'm having this markup:

```
<UL>
    <LI class=odd>bla</LI>
    <LI class=even>bla</LI>
    <LI class=odd>bla</LI>
    <LI class=even>bla</LI>
    <LI class=odd>bla</LI>
    <LI class=even>bla</LI>
</UL>
```

my question: how can i select all lis like "with class odd OR even" using just one selector?
i can't simply just use $("li") because the li's also might contain li's

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector):

```
$('li.odd, li.even');
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to speify those classes; you can simply write

```
$('ul.Root > li')
```

This will select all `<li>` elements that are *direct* children of the `<ul>` with class `Root`.
It won't select any nested `<li>`s.

You can select the parent `<ul>` using any class or ID selector you want.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you will want to change your tags to lowercase, and put your classes in quotes.

```
<ul>
    <li class="odd">bla</li>
    <li class="even">bla</li>
    <li class="odd">bla</li>
    <li class="even">bla</li>
    <li class="odd">bla</li>
    <li class="even">bla</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can select them this way

```
$('li.odd, li.even')
```

an even better way...

```
<ul id="theUl">
    <li class="odd">...</li>
    <li class="even">...</li>
    <li class="odd">...</li>
    <li class="even">...</li>
    <li class="odd">...</li>
    <li class="even">...</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$('#theUl li')
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
 $("li.odd, li.even")
```

By the way, you should use lower case for your tags.

Answer (score 2):

Like Nick Spiers said but make sure you add a tag name for efficiency

```
$("li.even") // selects only even class
$("li.odd")  // selects only odd class
$("li.even, li.odd") // selects both odd and even
```

Note if you make a selector without the tag name and only the class.  jQuery must iterate though all DOM elements to find matches.  if you us the tagname then jQuery makes use of document.getElementsByTagname() to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

class selectors

```
$("li.even") or $("li.odd")
```

To grab all li's with either of the 2 classes:

```
$("li.even, li.odd")
```

Comment: Wouldn't that include all li's? Or are there more on the page that you don't want to grab? in which case $("li.even, li.odd")

Answer (score 0):

Give your first ul a class or id:

```
<ul class="something">
</ul>

$('ul.something > li.even, ul.something > li.odd')
```

This only gets the highest li's